# no suitable method found to override c#

Tags: c#

I have tried a few things to fix the error and I just can't seem to figure this one out, I would greatly appreciate any help. The error is in both the Triangle and Square classes, the errors in Triangle are "does not implement inherited abstract member from GeometricFigure" and "no suitable method found to override" and Square has just the "no suitable method found to override" error.

```
namespace ShapesDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(8,10);
            Square squ = new Square(11, 12);
            Triangle tri = new Triangle(10, 20);
            Console.WriteLine("Computed area is {0}" + "\n\n" + "Computed Triangle is: {1}"         + "\n", squ.ComputeArea(rec.Area), tri.ComputeArea(rec.Area));

        }
    }

    abstract class GeometricFigure
    {
        public decimal _height, _width, _area;


        public decimal Height
        {
            get { return _height; }
            set { _height = value; }
        }

        public decimal Width
        {
            get { return _width; }
            set { _width = value; }
        }

        public decimal Area
        {
            get { return _area; }
        }

        public abstract decimal ComputeArea();

    }

    class Rectangle : GeometricFigure
    {
        private decimal height, width;

        public Rectangle(decimal sideA, decimal sideB)
        {
            this.height = sideA;
            this.width = sideB;
        }

        public Rectangle()
        {
        }

        public override decimal ComputeArea()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Area is" + _width.ToString(), _height.ToString());
            return width * height;
        }

    }

    class Square : Rectangle
    {
        public Square(decimal sideA, decimal sideB)
        {
            this._width = sideA;
            this._height = sideB;
            if (sideA != sideB)
                this._height = this._width;
        }

        public Square(decimal xy)
        {
            this._width = xy;
            this._height = this._width;
        }

        public override decimal ComputeArea(decimal _area)
        { return _area = this._width * this._height; }
    }

    class Triangle : GeometricFigure
    {
        public Triangle(int x, int y)
        {
            this.Width = x;
            this.Height = y;
        }

        public override decimal ComputeArea(decimal _area)
        { return _area = (this.Width * this.Height) / 2; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is worth emphasizing that removing the parameter as the answers say will resolve your problem, *and furthermore if it worked as you currently have it it would not work as you intended.* _area does not need to be re-declared in your method parameter as it is already a class field. What you have right now is assigning to the second declaration of _area within the scope of the function which is basically doing nothing since it is not doing anything to the class field, but instead to the assigning to the local declaration of _area within the method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever you override a method, you have to override with the same signature as in the base class (there are exceptions for covariance and contravariance, but those don't apply to your question, so I'll ignore them here).

In `GeometricFigure`, you have the declaration

```
public abstract decimal ComputeArea();
```

but in `Square` and `Triangle` you have the declaration

```
public override decimal ComputeArea(decimal _area)
{
    // ...
}
```

Let's say that some other class contained the following code:

```
GeometricFigure fig = new Triangle(10, 10);
decimal area = fig.ComputeArea();
```

Which `ComputeArea` would be called?  `Triangle` doesn't define a `ComputeArea` with no arguments, and neither does `GeometricFigure`, so there is no valid `ComputeArea` to call.  As a result, the language spec disallows this scenario by requiring that `override` only be placed on methods that actually override methods of the base class, with the same number and type of arguments.  Since `ComputeArea(decimal)` doesn't override `ComputeArea()`, the compiler errors out and tells you that you must place the override keyword on a `ComputeArea()` definition in `Triangle`, and that you can't put the override keyword on `ComputeArea(decimal)`.

That's not to say that you can't define a method `ComputeArea(decimal)` on `Triangle` and `Square`, but you can't declare it as overriding `ComputeArea()` in `GeometricFigure`.

Answer (score 4):

In your square and triangle classes, you need to remove the method parameter from ComputeArea() so that it matches the signature of the base class.